# Application.Run(new Main()) in Program.cs issue

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am developing a project in C# Winforms(Desktop Application). I have lots of forms in my project which Form I want to run on start I put it in **Program.cs** e.g.  **Application.Run(new Main());**
but it is not working. No matter which form instance I call in **Application.Run()** it keeps Loading **Generate_Challan()** form.
Kindly tell me what is the problem how to solve it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to the constructor of that form and hit F5, you will find how the code _actually_ gets executed.

Answer (score -1):

**To set the startup form in Windows Forms**

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and choose Properties.
   The Project property page opens with the Application properties displayed.
2. Choose the form you want as the startup form from the Startup Object drop-down list.

For more information see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2whfskf(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: The mothod is not working for me. in Startup object we can give the path of Program.cs that is what I did already again I write the name of form which I want to open in the program.cs but it still not working.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally deleted a file or a line of code. If it is easy, try make a new project and copy across the code and setup the form again.